# what are the largest and smallest numbers between 0 and 1 that C++ can represent internally without rounding?

Tags: c++, machine-learning, double, rounding, probability

I have a C++ function which computes probabilities based on a simple model. It seems that C++ tends to round very small probabilities to 0 and very large probabilities to 1. This results in issues in later computations (taking the log(p) and log(1-p)).

Is there a way to explicitly represent the largest number smaller than 1 which C++ can represent internally without rounding? And similarly, the smallest number greater than 0?

I could do something like this:

```
if (probability == 1) 
    probability = 0.999999999;
else if (probability == 0) 
    probability = 0.000000001;
```

but this results in other numerical issues (to do with accumulating numbers). Is there a more principled way, perhaps using numeric_limits?

Comment: `numeric_limits<long double>;` should tell you.

Comment: [cppreference page of numeric_limits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) `epsilon` and `rounding_error` in particular should interest you

Comment: Also, you might like `log1p` for "log (1-p)". It's more accurate when p is close to zero

Comment: Note that the smallest number is denormalized, which may cause issues. You may want to use the smallest non-denormalized number instead.

Comment: @Aaron, thanks for the suggestion. I'll look into it.

Comment: @rcgldr, can you elaborate?

Comment: @Aciel - take at look at subnormal and double precision examples in this wiki article: [exponent encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#Exponent_encoding)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While its name might be slightly misleading, [`std::numeric_limits<T>::min`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/min) is what you're looking for. For floating point types, it will give you the smallest value greater than zero.

For the greatest number that's still less than `1`, you can use [`std::nexttoward`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/nextafter) if you use C++11:

#### Code

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<cmath>
#include<limits>

int main(){
  printf("Near 0: %1.20e\nNear 1: %1.20e\n",
    std::numeric_limits<double>::min(),
    std::nexttoward(1.0, 0.0)
  );
  return 0;
}
```

#### Result

```
Near 0: 2.22507385850720138309e-308
Near 1: 9.99999999999999888978e-01
```

Comment: Interesting. These values appear to be even more extreme than DBL_EPSILON. One question, does numeric_limits give different values depending on the platform the code is run on?

Comment: Yes, since *"[t]here are three floating point types: float, double, and long double. The type double provides at least
as much precision as float, and the type long double provides at least as much precision as double.
The set of values of the type float is a subset of the set of values of the type double; the set of values
of the type double is a subset of the set of values of the type long double. The value representation of
floating-point types is implementation-defined."* The standard leaves the actual implementation of types up to the compiler/platform.

Answer (score 0):

C++ `double` variable is double-precision floating-point number. The IEEE 754 standard specifies a binary64 as having:

- Sign bit: 1 bit
- Exponent width: 11 bits
- Significand precision: 53 bits (52 explicitly stored)

This gives 15–17 significant decimal digits precision. If a decimal string with at most 15 significant digits is converted to IEEE 754 double precision representation and then converted back to a string with the same number of significant digits, then the final string should match the original. Check [this document](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/ieee754status/IEEE754.PDF) for more information.

Comment: C++ does not require IEE 754 compatibility. It certainly doesn't require the now archaic 80 bit extended double type.

Comment: @AlanStokes yet both Intel compiler and GCC implement it. Though long double is required only to be as precious as double, which is done in Visual C++

Comment: It exists on some platforms. It is not used on x64, nor by default on more recent versions of gcc on x86, nor by any 32 bit version of Visual Studio. And it has always been Intel specific.

Comment: @AlanStokes OK. I see.

Answer (score -1):

You could use `<cfloat>` header by using `DBL_EPSILON` (or `FLT_EPSILON` according to your data type):

`DBL_EPSILON` is defined as the smallest value such that `1.0 + DBL_EPSILON != 1.0` which should suit your requirement.

```
#include <cfloat>

if (probability == 1.0)
  probability = 1.0 - DBL_EPSILON;
else if (probability == 0.0f)
  probability = DBL_EPSILON;
```

Or you can use `<limits>` header and possibly parametrize it on your floating point type:

```
#include <limits>
if (probability == 1.0)
  probability = 1.0 - std::numeric_limit<double>::epsilon();
else if (probability == 0.0f)
  probability = std::numeric_limit<double>::epsilon();
```

Actually the latter returns value defined by the first approach so there is no difference in implementation.

Comment: Why not `std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon` and `::min`?

Comment: @Zeta: because he didn't specify C++11 tag.

Comment: Both have been in C++ before C++11. They just got `constexpr` in C++11.

Comment: @Zeta: edited to reflect both solutions, but I don't get the `::min` requirement, could you please clarify?

Comment: "If you have access to `<limits>`" is misleading. It's part of the standard library since 1998.

Comment: @Jack, thanks, the first solution worked for me. I'm just running a few test cases.

Comment: I expect because in C++ we prefer idiomatic C++ code rather than C.